# "<type>" is not exported from "./path"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to import a named value from one file and from that other I just export it as it should be but still some errors. I'm retrieving it from the current directory.

```
export type Homes = { ....

import {Homes} from './api';
```

I don't think it's relevant but, I import from js file and export from ts file.

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript file cannot import a type, as a type is a purely Typescript concept that does not correspond to a Javascript object (unlike, say, an exported class or function).

Comment: should I create an object in js and then try to convert it in my ts file somehow?

Comment: @lolttr11 I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, could you be a bit more descriptive in your main question?

Comment: I Have two components: one is a Modal (child) and the second one is the main (parent), and in the Modal, I want to create an object and then calls a certain parent's function with that object as an argument. the problem is that the function accepts a typed object. this is the reason I tried importing the type into the modal from the beginning.